# call REST api in particular time interval with incremental value in url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, url

In my application i want display a image slider with every 5 seconds limit. Getting a response image url form api for sending a request data. The sending request url is incremental url. *data1* *data2* so on...

```
 function imageUrl(i){
    $.ajax({
      url:"http://localhost:8080/api/Data"+i,
      method:"post",
      async:false,
      success: function(resp){
        //console.log(resp.image.url);
        url_resp = resp.image.url;
      }
    });
  $("#imgloc").attr('src',url_resp);
  }
setInterval(imageUrl, 5000);
```

Comment: Please be a little more specific. Are you encountering a specific problem? What have you tried?

Comment: In that api having set of data with id. i want to sent the id through the request and receiving the image url response and set as image src. Every 5 seconds i have to change the image to next id. So i need to send another ajax request to that api with next id. is that any way to increment that id in every ajax request url?

Comment: @BalajiSekar, you have an infinite number of `Data#`'s.  You seem to be trying to call this url every second with a forever increasing value of `i`.  Doesn't sound like a good idea to me...

Comment: @Steve0, yaah. I accepted. I am searching another way. Thanks guys.